# How to find SelectedValue based on SelectedText in a Dropdownlist in asp .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to find a SelectedValue using a SelectedText in asp .net c#?

Comment: I do have this table, that when user clicked a table row, whatever text inside the cell will be the considered as `SelectedText`. Though I cannot get the 'SelectedValue', because as what I have mentioned it is just a `text` coming from the table cell. Note that, the `table` cell value or text I am mentioning is part of options in the `Dropdownlist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't use the DropDownList's `SelectedValue` property directly?

Well, if you have a string and want the `Value` of the DropDownList's `ListItem` which has this string as `Text` you could use LINQ:

```
string value = ddl.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Text == text)?.Value;
```